# Athena partitioning when objects have random prefixes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

**Context:**

We would like to use Athena to query on an S3 bucket that follow the AWS-suggested best practice of [prefixing object names with a uniformly distributed value](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html):

```
s3://datasets-daily/<random-prefix>/format=parquet/dataset=navigation/year=2015/month=12/day=31/subregion=000/slice=01/part-00292-ddbc7e53-8256-46de-a1c3-55f65f808c96.c000.gz.parquet
```

This dataset is 40TB across 850k files and 140k partitions. Our partition limit has been increased to 250k.

**Question:**

Can `msck repair table_name` automatically partition data in this structure or are we expected to manually define every partition for every key since we're using the prefix?

**Experiments:**

We've tested creating tables and applying `msck` with the following results:

`LOCATION 's3://datasets-daily/` --> `msck` times out; `SELECT *` returns nothing

`LOCATION 's3://datasets-daily/*/` --> `msck` completes quickly; `SELECT *` returns nothing

In the first scenario the query times out after ten hours:

`2017/05/22 20:57:36 UTC-5  MSCK REPAIR TABLE datasets_daily N/A FAILED 36003.56 0KB`

Comment: When you say never completes, how long have you waited? That one as you have described there should be fine, it might just take a while...

Comment: @Henry updated with details. Times out after ten hours on 40TB / 800k file bucket.

Comment: I would consider putting in a support ticket. Also, have you tried adding partitions manually? There is a HiveQL query which does manual addition of partitions. It may be easier to programmatically do this, rather than trying to do the `msck repair table`